# Struts 1.x reset attribute

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I'm currently working on a legacy application that was using an older Struts 1.x version that I can't determine because of bad CVS versioning. For reasons out of my control, I must make this application run in Struts 1.2.9.

On my struts-config.xml i have a few actions that have a reset attribute defined with the value false. Ex.:

```
<action path="/xxx" scope="session" name="xxxBean" type="com.xxx.yyy.XXXAction" validate="false" parameter="oper" reset="false">
```

Apparently, in this struts version this reset attribute is now longer supported. Since there is no struts documentation available older than 1.3.5 in the apache documentation archive I'm not finding any info on what this did.

Can somebody tell me what was the purpose of this attribute and how can I support the same functionality in the latter Struts 1.x versions?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: What is a reset tag?

Comment: The reset xml tag that is in my example. It is possible it does not exist at all and it's an error of the previous developer. My question is precisely what is the purpose of this tag.

Comment: In your example there isn't the reset tag. Your question ultimately unclear what are you asking.

Comment: All previous versions of Struts are still available for download and they include the docs: http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/. There's no `reset` parameter in 1.2.7 in the DTD (I can't find 1.2.9 at the moment), perhaps it's a custom parameter? Does the app have its own DTD? Custom request processor?

Comment: @DaveNewton, Thanks I will check it. The app doesn't have it's own DTD and I never saw previous executions, but with Struts 1.2.9. I get the unknown parameter error. I thought it could be a valid parameter in 1.1x or 1.0x.

Comment: @RomanC i meant reset attribute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.